# Validate URL without any http , https or ftp

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need to validate a url.

```
var urlPattern = new RegExp("(http|ftp|https)://[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;/~+#-])?");
```

If the URL have `http`,`https` or `ftp` i can validate. Incase if that URL does not have `http`,`ftp` or `https` means how can i validate?

Comment: If you are happy your current regexp is correct, but you just want to also validate _without_ any protocol, you can just remove the protocol part: `(http|ftp|https)://`?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
var regex = new RegExp("^(http[s]?:\\/\\/(www\\.)?|ftp:\\/\\/(www\\.)?|www\\.){1}([0-9A-Za-z-\\.@:%_\+~#=]+)+((\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})+)(/(.)*)?(\\?(.)*)?"); 
var without_regex = new RegExp("^([0-9A-Za-z-\\.@:%_\+~#=]+)+((\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})+)(/(.)*)?(\\?(.)*)?");
var str = "url";
if(regex.test(str) || without_regex.test(str)){
    alert("Successful");
}else{
    alert("No match");
}
```

It accepts the following urls:

```
https://example.com
http://example.com
ftp://example.com
www.example.com
https://www.example.com
http://www.example.com
ftp://www.example.com
example.com
```

Comment: how to change this /^((http(s?)|ftp):\/\/)?[A-z0-9_\-\.]+... checking a URL without http and https.

Comment: 2 or 3 characters for TLD is **really** short, see [TLD list](https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help

```
 var url = 'http://www.Jamboo.com';
 var correctUrl= /^(ftp|http|https):\/\/[^ "]+$/.test(url);
  // true
```

or

```
  var r = /^(ftp|http|https):\/\/[^ "]+$/;
  r.test('http://www.Jam  boo.com');
   // false
```

Comment: how to change this  `/^((http(s?)|ftp):\/\/)?[A-z0-9_\-\.]+...` checking a URL without http and https

Comment: I need to accept as a URL without http and https also

Comment: try replacing this /^:\/\/[^ "]+$/.test(url);

Comment: sorry I can't understand

Answer (score 0):

**Regex**:

> /(?(?:(http|https|ftp)://)?(?:((?:[^\W\s]|.|-|[:]{1})+)@{1})?((?:www.)?(?:[^\W\s]|.|-)+[.][^\W\s]{2,4}|localhost(?=/)|\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3})(?::(\d*))?([/]?[^\s\?]*[/]{1})*(?:/?([^\s\n\?[]{}#]*(?:(?=.)){1}|[^\s\n\?[]{}.#]*)?([.]{1}[^\s\?#]*)?)?(?:\?{1}([^\s\n#[]]*))?([#][^\s\n]*)?)?/g

**HTML**

```
<input type= text id = 'url'>
```

**JS**

```
$('#url').on('blur', function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  if(val.match(/\(?(?:(http|https|ftp):\/\/)?(?:((?:[^\W\s]|\.|-|[:]{1})+)@{1})?((?:www.)?(?:[^\W\s]|\.|-)+[\.][^\W\s]{2,4}|localhost(?=\/)|\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})(?::(\d*))?([\/]?[^\s\?]*[\/]{1})*(?:\/?([^\s\n\?\[\]\{\}\#]*(?:(?=\.)){1}|[^\s\n\?\[\]\{\}\.\#]*)?([\.]{1}[^\s\?\#]*)?)?(?:\?{1}([^\s\n\#\[\]]*))?([\#][^\s\n]*)?\)?/g) != null)
      alert('success');
})
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/mayank_shubham/73ejutjs/)

**Alternately use:**

```
$('#url').on('blur', function() {
    var urlPattern = new RegExp("((http|ftp|https)://)?[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;/~+#-])?");
  var val = $(this).val();
  if(urlPattern.test(val)) {
    alert('success');
  } else {
    alert('fail')
  }
})
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/mayank_shubham/73ejutjs/1/)

Comment: how to change this /^((http(s?)|ftp):\/\/)?[A-z0-9_\-\.]+... checking a URL without http and https.

Comment: 'var urlPattern = new RegExp("((http|ftp|https)://)?[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;/~+#-])?");' also works

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the regex of @Shubham Khatri I would suggest (if possible, of course) to use external tools like `wget` or `curl` to query the address and check the result.

Answer (score 0):

**Regex for URL without protocol**

```
/^[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w\.-]+)+[\w\-\._%~:/?#[\]@!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=.]+$/
```

[Try it here](https://www.regextester.com/116006)

Comment: The negative lookahead at the beginning is completly useless.

Comment: Your regex matches `[\w.-]+` as first characters, so check that string doesn't begin with `://` is useless, just remove the lookahead, the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

### Match Regex without (http|https|www)

```
    /^(?!https?)(?!www\.?).*\..+$/g
```

This regex will work for

```
    google.com
    mail.google.com
    app.firebase.google.com
    google.com/something
```

This regex will not work for

```
    www.google.com
    http://google.com
    http://www.google.com
```